# ERROR: Failed to resolve: com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.1.0

Tags: android, firebase

While trying to connect Google Firebase to my Android Studio project, I keep getting `"ERROR: failed to resolve: com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.1.0"` whenever I try to sync my project.

I've seen multiple people with similar problems but none of their solutions seem to work for me. (though they seem to work for them)

Android Studio says the problem is in my build.gradle (Module: app) file. here it is below:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.myapplication"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.1.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:16.1.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'

}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Thank you very much for your time and assistance on this matter.

Answer (score 2):

The latest build for firebase-core is `16.0.8`

try this:

```
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.8'
```

here is the link for all firebase dependencies:
[Firebase](https://firebase.google.com/docs/android/setup)

scroll all the way down and you will find the latest.

Comment: I had similar problem even with explicit implementation dependency to 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.8', the 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.1.0' still seemed to require firebase-core:16.1.0. What helped me was upgrading google-services plugin, e.i. classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.2.0' in buildscript/dependencies in top-level build.gradle.